# VBA macro converting time to PST

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime, timezone

```
Dim dt As Object, utc As Date
Set dt = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
dt.SetVarDate Now
utc = dt.GetVarDate(False)
```

Hello! I just saw this code somewhere in this page, but this code converts the time to UTC.

But can someone help me to convert it to PST instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Check https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/612mdp/converting_datetime_utc_to_pst/

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't find the answer to my question. I didn't use the excel to run the dates/time, i use it inside the code in VBA

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Sub TimeOnMyHands()
    Dim dt As Object, utc As Date, pst As Date
    Set dt = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
    
    dt.SetVarDate Now
    utc = dt.GetVarDate(False)
    pst = utc - TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)

    MsgBox utc & vbCrLf & pst
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped a lot. Thanks mate!